# Making Document Sets unique

Tags: 2010, document-set, unique

Is there anyway I can get a Document Sets to be unique? If I set one column to "Enforce Unique Values", I think it will look at the files inside the document set and error saying:

> Error: This field contains duplicate values. Remove all duplicate values and
>   try the operation again.

How can I have a Document Set library with unique values? I would like to specify it by Name, but that column in not configurable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could write an event receiver for Item-Added that would check the property you are interested in like Name and ensure it is unique.